# Gradle flavours - apps cache

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In my application I use `Gradle` flavors:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.application"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.4.1"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
            storeFile file("C:\\!Dev\\KeyStore\\xxxxx")
            storePassword = "xxxxx"
            keyAlias = "xxxxx"
            keyPassword = "xxxxx"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig

            // adds version to file name
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def outputFile = output.outputFile
                    if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                        def fileName = outputFile.name.replace('.apk', "-${versionName}.apk")
                        output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
                    }
                }
            }
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        MyAppLocal {
            applicationId "com.my.application.local"
            versionName "1.4.1.1"
            versionCode 13
        }

        MyAppLocal202{
            applicationId "com.my.application.local202"
            versionName "1.4.1.1"
            versionCode 13
        }

        MyAppTest {
            applicationId "com.my.application.test"
        }

        MyAppTest2 {
            applicationId "com.my.application.test2"
        }

        MyAppProduction {
            applicationId "com.my.application"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
    compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
}
```

All flavor versions are installed on same device.
Some times the app crashes after pressing the launcher icon without any exceptions.
The only "interesting" log was:

```
ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord
```

The problem solved after manually clearing the application cache (apps-> click on app -> clear data)
.

Does different flavors uses the same chache/ `SharedPreferences` ?
How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 3):

Does different flavors uses the same cache/ SharedPreferences ?

No if your flavors have different applicationID. SharedPreferences is just xml file. And android store this file in internal storage by following path: /data/data/${applicationID}. 
So SharedPreferences shouldn't be a reason of your issue.

How to solve that problem?

Could you update your question with more stack trace.